# restore win11 entry in grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 22.04

I have a dual-boot system with win 11 and ubuntu 22.04 with the the OSs on two different drives (M2 drive for windows and ssd for ubuntu). At the begenning win 11 was pre-installed on the machine and then I installed ubuntu and all worked fine.
Unfortunately I faced some trouble with win11 and I had to reinstall it. Now when I start the system I can't see win 11 entry in the grub menu anymore.
First, I simply tried to update the grub with:
`sudo update-grub`
but this didn't work.

Then I tried to reinstall the grub with:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` where the grub is (and should be) and then

`sudo update-grub` but the win 11 entry didn't appear.
How can I restore the win 11 entry?

Thanks

Additional information:

`sudo os-prober` successfully see win 11 and also `efibootmgr`
successfully lists the boot order with win11 at the second place.

Comment: Is Windows fast startup on. Or is bitlocker on? You did reinstall in UEFI boot mode?

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what was the solution for me, I reply my own question.

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

then I added the following line:

`GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`

after saved the changes, I run:
`sudo update-grub`

and at the reboot the windows 11 entry appeared again in the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, regarding your question, I have tried this way of solving the problem and it has worked for me.

Install os-prober on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt update -y

sudo apt install os-prober
```

Then you can modify the /etc/default/grub file by adding the following line to it:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Make sure the the EFI partition where the Windows bootloader resides is mounted.

Run as root:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Finally you should update the grub configuration and restart the computer so that you can check that everything works correctly.

```
sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```